# Using JUST for C#, is it possible to normalize double-serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

We have a microservice which receives events from Salesforce and then publishes them to the Azure Service Bus.

Salesforce events can't normally contain child records nor lists.
As a hack, we are serializing this data and stuffing it into a long text.

Our microservice has the ability to take the Salesforce input and apply [JUST](https://github.com/WorkMaze/JUST.net) templates to the input before forwarding the result to the Azure service bus.  JUST stands for "JSON Under Simple Transformation" and this is a library to transform JSON, similar to how XSL can transform XML.

So, we might receive a JSON which looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "zowqvqZB821tITs2yGoDPQ",
    "payload": {
      "Account__c": "{\"BillingCity__c\":\"Frankfurt0.7402008498784405\",\"BillingCountry__c\":\"Germany0.034598927398245216\"}",
      "OpportunityLineItems__c": "[{\"SystemName__c\":\"SF\",\"Currency__c\":\"EUR\"},{\"SystemName__c\":\"SF\",\"Currency__c\":\"USD\"}]"
    },
    "event": {
      "replayId": 5507836
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/Contract__e"
}
```

We'd like to normalize this double serialized data, transforming strings containing JSON into unwrapped objects or arrays.  So, it should end up like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "zowqvqZB821tITs2yGoDPQ",
    "payload": {
      "Account__c": {
          "BillingCity__c": "Frankfurt0.7402008498784405",
          "BillingCountry__c": "Germany0.034598927398245216"
      },
      "OpportunityLineItems__c": [
       {
          "SystemName__c": "SF",
          "Currency__c": "EUR"
       }, 
       {
          "SystemName__c": "SF",
          "Currency__c": "USD"
       }]
    },
    "event": {
      "replayId": 5507836
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/Contract__e"
}
```

I've tried to create the following custom function:

```
using LanguageExt;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions;

public class NormalizeSerialization
{
    public static Either<JToken, string> TryUnquote(string quotedJson)
    {
        try
        {
            return JToken.Parse(quotedJson);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return quotedJson;
        }
    }
}
```

and then include a call to this in the JUST template like:

```
{
    "account": "#customfunction(Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions,Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions.NormalizeSerialization.TryUnquote,#valueof($.payloadProperties.Account__c))"
}
```

but this results in

> System.Exception: 'Error while calling function :
> #customfunction(Enpal.Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions,Enpal.Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions.NormalizeSerialization.TryUnquote,#valueof($.payloadProperties.Account__c))
>
> - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')'

Putting a breakpoint into the static function did not help as the system does not seem able break from within the function.

How can I make this work?

Comment: The question may make sense to you but is very hard to understand for anyone else. JUST is a little-known library. You'll have to explain what it does first so people can understand what you ask. `Normalization` has several meanings but none of them seems to be relevant here. `Either` is a functional concept that has nothing to do with normalization. There's no example of the source JSON (much less an explanation why it needs "unquoting") or a desired output. It's unclear what you mean by "unwrapped objects or arrays"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, hope my edits help.

Comment: It looks like JUST can't resolve the type given to `#customfunction()` which I assume is the first parameter of it. Indeed you're only giving it the _namespace_ `Enpal.Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions` instead of the _type name_ `Enpal.Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions.NormalizeSerialization`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: What also might cause the issue is that the assembly that's executing JUST has no reference to the assembly containing the function to call. You can enforce that. E.g. with a field like `private Enpal.Salesforce.EventListener.Just.CustomFunctions.NormalizeSerialization dummyReference;` in some part of that code.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, cheers for response.  Tried both suggestions, but so far, no joy.  :-(

Comment: So, I've discovered part of the problem is that I was using the wrong NuGet, but even correcting this, I discovered the system is confused about where to look for the DLL.... so now I've opened this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175040/how-can-i-tell-my-c-sharp-project-where-to-look-for-dlls  .... I don't know yet whether the answer will be enough or just a stepping stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my Normalizer to look like this:

```
public class Normalizer
{
    public static object TryUnquote(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            return value is string quotedValue
                ? JToken.Parse(quotedValue)
                : value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then registered it on JsonTransformer like this:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddJustCustomFunctions(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _ = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Normalizer));

        JUSTContext context = new();
        context.RegisterCustomFunction("Enpal.JUST.CustomFunctions", "CustomFunctions.Normalizer", "TryUnquote", "tryunquote");

        return services.AddSingleton(new JsonTransformer(context));
    }
```