# How can I tell my C# project where to look for DLLs?

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, dllregistration

I'm currently trying to use custom functions with [JUST.Net](https://github.com/WorkMaze/JUST.net).

I've created this function in a project called `Foo.JUST.CustomFunctions`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace CustomFunctions;

public class Normalizer
{
    public static object TryUnquote(object value) =>
        value is string quotedValue
            ? JToken.Parse(quotedValue)
            : value;
}
```

I am trying to register it with:

```cs
// FIXME: Use Dependency Injection!
JUSTContext context = new();

context.RegisterCustomFunction("Enpal.JUST.CustomFunctions", "CustomFunctions.Normalizer", "TryUnquote", "tryunquote");
```

But the system throws this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'C:\projects\SalesforceEventListenerService\Salesforce.EventListener\Foo.JUST.CustomFunctions.dll'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.'

Which makes perfect sense because Visual Studio is not putting it there when it builds the project but rather it can be found in `"C:\projects\SalesforceEventListenerService\Salesforce.EventListener\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows8.0"`

How can I make sure the system looks in the right place?

And what, if anything, more will I need to do to make sure this also works when it hits the Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: If you want to fix the symptom, you can handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.  But probably better to find the root cause.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Cheers for the response.  Care to elaborate how I might either do the handling or search for the root cause?

Comment: Handling AssemblyResolve is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads    Basically when .NET can't figure out the file path, you have the chance to find the DLL yourself, load it, and return it to .NET which will go on without raising FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Cheers.... Looks promising for local development, but I'm not sure what I'd need to do with the solution so it would continue to work when it hits the pipeline and eventually gets deployed to an Azure App Service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working like so:

```
_ = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Normalizer));

JUSTContext context = new();
context.RegisterCustomFunction("Enpal.JUST.CustomFunctions", "CustomFunctions.Normalizer", "TryUnquote", "tryunquote");
```

Comment: Nice solution, force .NET to go find it while your code is active, before the other library gets a chance to reconfigure search paths.